# Bind/Named DNS server on ISPConfig sometimes working

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone, named-conf

I have Installed preconfigured system with ISPConfig panel on VPS server. When I create DNS zones and configure them, server work for some time then for some time **timeouts** and global dns (like 8.8.8.8) lose records and domain in unreachable (couldn't find server).

Ports are Open. While there is timeout on DNS server (which is running, i checked) i can without problem connect on port 53 via telnet.

OS: Centos 6, BIND 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.4

When I query server with `dig ANY dekorate.pl @5.133.13.32` i get timeout. And after a while it will work normally.

> named-checkconf /var/named/pri.dekorate.pl

```
/var/named/pri.dekorate.pl:1: unknown option '$TTL'
/var/named/pri.dekorate.pl:3: unknown option 'serial,'
/var/named/pri.dekorate.pl:4: unknown option 'refresh,'
/var/named/pri.dekorate.pl:5: unknown option 'retry,'
/var/named/pri.dekorate.pl:6: unknown option 'expire,'
/var/named/pri.dekorate.pl:7: unknown option 'minimum,'
/var/named/pri.dekorate.pl:10: unknown option '*'
/var/named/pri.dekorate.pl:20: unexpected token near end of file
```

Configuration file that ISPConfig generated.

```
$TTL        3600
@       IN      SOA     ns1.dekorate.pl. admin.dekorate.pl. (
                        2015040604       ; serial, todays date + todays serial #
                        7200              ; refresh, seconds
                        540              ; retry, seconds
                        604800              ; expire, seconds
                        86400 )            ; minimum, seconds
;

* 86400 A        5.133.13.32
dekorate.pl. 3600 A        5.133.13.32
dekorate.pl. 3600      MX    10   mail.dekorate.pl.
dekorate.pl. 3600      NS        ns1.dekorate.pl.
dekorate.pl. 3600      NS        ns2.dekorate.pl.
mail 3600 A        5.133.13.32
ns1 86400 A        5.133.13.32
ns2 86400 A        5.133.13.32
www 3600 A        5.133.13.32
```

To note: on panel of my domain registrar i delegated domain to ns1.dokrate.pl and ns2.dekorate.pl **with filling IP adress**

**UPDATE**

It currently again stopped to work. I did (on on my local machine):

```
nc -u -z -v 5.133.13.32 53
Connection to 5.133.13.32 53 port [udp/domain] succeeded!
```

and:

```
dig ANY dekorate.pl @5.133.13.32
; <<>> DiG 9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-20.P1.el5_8.4 <<>> ANY dekorate.pl @5.133.13.32
;; global options:  printcmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

and on server i did:

```
 dig ANY dekorate.pl @localhost

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.4 <<>> ANY dekorate.pl @localhos                                          t
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 39
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 3
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dekorate.pl.                   IN      ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
dekorate.pl.            3600    IN      A       5.133.13.32
dekorate.pl.            3600    IN      MX      10 mail.dekorate.pl.
dekorate.pl.            3600    IN      NS      ns2.dekorate.pl.
dekorate.pl.            3600    IN      NS      ns1.dekorate.pl.
dekorate.pl.            3600    IN      SOA     ns1.dekorate.pl. admin.dekorate.                                          pl. 2015040604 7200 540 604800 86400

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
mail.dekorate.pl.       3600    IN      A       5.133.13.32
ns1.dekorate.pl.        86400   IN      A       5.133.13.32
ns2.dekorate.pl.        86400   IN      A       5.133.13.32

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Apr  6 17:23:53 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 192
```

Whenever it happens. Google DNS servers lose ability to resolve it.

```
dig ANY dekorate.pl @8.8.8.8

; <<>> DiG 9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-20.P1.el5_8.4 <<>> ANY dekorate.pl @8.8.8.8
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 29463
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dekorate.pl.                   IN      ANY

;; Query time: 3081 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Mon Apr  6 15:28:47 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 29
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research with ISP it turned out that answer to this riddle is: We were being caught by UDP Connection limit set on IP. Limit got taken down and everything works.

Comment: I have the same problem, how did you take down the. limit?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'm currently unable to reproduce the problem.

I'm not sure if any of this actually answers the question (I'm not sure there even really is a clear question) but here is my take on what has been presented:

- **`named-checkzone`** is the tool appropriate for **testing a zone file**
  (`named-checkconf` is for the named configuration file).
- You should have **more than one nameserver**. I assume your registrar had
  a rule for that which you got around by making two `NS` records
  (`ns{1,2}.dekorate.pl`) but as these resolve to the same address you've really just found a way to get around their policy enforcement instead of accepting the norm of having multiple nameservers (as diversely situated as possible) for increased reliability.
- **DNS primarily uses UDP**, not TCP. Your test with **`telnet` uses TCP**, which is only relevant for some edge cases. (To actually make a dns test that matches up with `telnet` in terms of connectivity you could do `dig +tcp ...`.)
- From having tried the example query I have noted that you appear to allow **recursion requests from everyone**. This is a **very bad idea** which practically invites abuse.

All in all, are you really up for running your own nameservers?
If your actual goal is something else it may be better not to run additional infrastructure of your own unless it's really necessary.

Comment: Acually, I don't want to run them at all. But for VPS server they don't provide DNS servers like for regular hosting. I assumed, that ISPConfig server  DNS zones are working configured and are correctly.
Also, how you configure domain for a dns server? I mean, did I do it correctly?
If server i down, dns is down. DNS is only for this specific server. Does DNS need to be more realible for this server than server itself?

Comment: Updated my problem with some more info.

Comment: Your dns usually wont adversely affect the website for very long, but it will affect emails. Often a domain will bounce back quickly on the http side of things even after an extended downtime of dns. but email takes longer. When they say upto 48 hours for propagation they generally mean email services but it can take that for http too.

Answer (score 0):

Run in to this my self. DNS record would not update no matter how many edits on ISPconfig. Solution was fairly simple.
When you make a mistake in the zone configuration bind will produce **.err** file in /etc/bind folder. That will contain your "new" zone settings but old settings will stay as long as the error remains in your configuration.
In my case it was faulty **SRV** record. After deleting it ispconfig/bind used the proper configuration file instead of the old one.